# Passing a Blaze Template as a Parameter to a function creates Famous.js surface

Tags: meteor, famo.us, meteor-blaze

I am trying to update my famous.js surfaces' `content` by using Meteor's `Blaze.toHTMLWithData(template, data)`, like `Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.roomIlanSpecsTemplate, data)`, with a custom template in a function creating a famous `surface` inside a famous `view`. I want to pass the template in the `cursorToArray` function depending on the type of document returned to its callbacks. But I cannot have a rendered page on the browser, even there is no error in the console. If I use hardcoded version like having `createFn` function for each different template and then defininig and `cursorToArray` fucntion with that function it works.

What can be the thing I miss here?

```
    cursorToArray = function(cursor, renderablesArray, template, createFn){
    //each callback should decide which createFn to use based on result document, cos each result has a different template so a createFn.
    cursor.observe({
    addedAt: function(document, atIndex, before) {
        renderablesArray.splice(atIndex, 0, createFn(document, template));//createRoomIlanView, createRoomRenterIlanView, createFriendLookupIlanView
    },
    changedAt: function(newDocument, oldDocument, atIndex) {
        renderablesArray[atIndex] = createFn(newDocument, template);
    },
    });
}
cursorToArray(Ilans.find(), ilanViews, Template.roomIlanSpecsTemplate, createIlanView);
```

portion of the createFn definiton:

```
function createIlanView(data, template){
        var ilanSpecsSurface = new Surface({
          content: Blaze.toHTMLWithData(template, data), 
          properties: {
            fontSize: "14px"
          }
        });

        return ilanSpecsSurface;
    }
```

Comment: Where are you adding your new `Surface` to the context of `FamousEngine`

Comment: I have edited the tags accordingly.

Comment: actual create... function creates a famo.us `view`. adn adds some branches with `modifiers` and `surfaces` to them. the Surface above is one the surfaces at the tip of these brances stemming from the `view`.

Comment: and this views are used to populate an array and it serves as the sequence of the scrollview I use in the content part of the headerfooterlayout.

Comment: I think te problem is with passing the argument of the `Blaze` function call in the content of the surface. If it is hardcoded as I meant in Q it works; `Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.roomIlanSpecsTemplate, data)`. But I want to simplfy it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is all about older Famous what about using Reactive Surface from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30445791/2288496

```
var ReactiveTemplate = famodev.ReactiveTemplate;


var reactive = new ReactiveTemplate({
   template: Template.mytemplate,
   data: Collection.find().fetch(),
   properties: {}
});
```

A good example how to implement Routing, Subscriptions etc. https://github.com/sayawan/flowwy